# datatable rowspan with scrollCollapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My Problem start with large data,
I am using jquery datatable to create table, I have to provide solution like:

1. Extra Columns can be added (Done)
2. RowSpan (Merge Columns with same values and show hierarchy wise)
3. Apply Click Function to collapse rows.

Since I have large data, I am using **scrollCollapse** and **scrollY** property if datatable which automatically handles large dataset by limiting it to viewport.

Now How to apply rowspan so that it can work with scrolling feature.
[image]

Comment: In case anyone wants to check Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/stiwari/cmvxh99j

Comment: Allan has stated that datatables do not support rowspans here https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/76315/#Comment_76315  so I would probably initialize datatable as an empty table then build the table itself with javascript/jquery

Comment: I have added code in jquery to add rowspan, but issue is when you have scrollCollapse it re renders the tr which causes buggy nature in rowspan.